# Manually invoke a UITableViewCell's reordering control

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Within the current UITableView functionality, you can set a cell to editable and click & drag its reordering control. Is there anyway to invoke this reordering control and perhaps place it over the entire cell?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. You seem to answer your own question ("you can set a cell to editable", "Is there anyway...")?

Comment: You can set a cell to editable, which creates a reordering control on the right-hand side of the cell. The question is if I can create that reordering control manually -- not just have it be an effect of setting a cell to editable.

Comment: UITableViewCell:showsReorderControl ?